# latexsym and url with tikzposter: warning about size

Tags: fonts, fontsize, tikzposter

When including `latexsym`, using the `\url` command from the `url` package in a `tikzposter` document results in a warning: “Font shape `U/lasy/m/n' in size <29.86> not available size <24.88> substituted on input line 7”, as illustrated in this minimal example.

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\block{Context and goal of this poster}{
    See \url{https://github.com/oliviercailloux/formal-framework-dj}.
}
\end{document}
```

Why does `latexsym` have this impact on `url`? According to the manual of `latexsym`, it is not supposed to change the font used by `url` (if this is what happens). In fact, the size of the url does not appear too small, or at least, it is not obvious to me. What happens here? Should I take the warning seriously? How can I get rid of it?

Comment: The `latexsym` package was last updated meaningfully about 25 years ago, and it should only be used at present for LaTeX documents that employ so-called "LaTeX2.09 compatibility mode". LaTeX2.09 was superseded by LaTeX2e in 1994. In all likelihood, you should be loading `amssymb` instead of `latexsym`.

Comment: For sure, if I replace `\usepackage{latexsym}` with `\usepackage{amssymb}` in your code, it compiles without the warning message you encountered.

Comment: I actually want to use `ntheorem`. Which “uses the `amssymb` and `latexsym` (automatically loaded) packages”, according to its manual. I noticed that the problem was coming from `latexsym`, hence simplified the example to make it a more direct question. Note that loading `amsmath` instead of `latexsym` also produces a warning about font size.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the fact that the `ntheorem` package loads the `latexsym` package; that's a bad mistake, IMNSHO. (Somebody should alert the maintainer(s) of the `ntheorem` package.) It's good, though, that `ntheorem`  loads the `amssymb` package, as that package loads the `amsfonts` package automatically. The saving grace, I suppose, is that `amsfonts` is an extension of, and major improvement on, `latexsym`.